# Geany "Find in files" breaks when brackets included in search string

Tags: regex, grep, find, geany, findinfiles

I have Geany 1.27 installed in my [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr). But I also have Windows 7 OS with Geany 1.28 installed.

In both these versions of Geany, when I try to find a string into a multiple files or folder with file-type filter of "phtml" or "php", I see that when my search string includes `(` or `)` (for example, `function new(`) the search fails.

Now I have a slight idea that this could be due to un-escaped bracket in string acting as part of Regex in `grep` command. Am I right?

How can I overcome the unescaped characters in search string when searching in Geany? In both Ubuntu and Windows Geany if the method could be different.

Comment: What does your actual `grep` command look like?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you properly escape your braces, as depending on options, you have set the regular expression is used for searching.

Your function search would be something like `new\(\)`. [The documentation](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#regular-expressions) is more detailed.